# active voice and passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

What is the passive voice  of:

> "I will convey my decision to you in a week"
>
> 1. My decision will be conveyed to you in a week by me.
> 2. You will be conveyed my decision in a week by me.

Comment: #2 would be at the very least an "unusual" use of ***conveyed*** (we'd more naturally say *You will be **told / informed of** my decision in a week*, and I can't see the point of including ***by me***). But both your examples are inherently clumsy, primarily *because* they use the passive voice. Just don't.

Comment: You've probably said or heard things like ***I'll see you tomorrow*** many times in natural conversation. But you probably *haven't* heard ***You will be seen by me tomorrow*** except in some oddball contrived context such as your doctor confirming that your medical checkup with him is due tomorrow.

Comment: "My decision will be conveyed to you in a week".

Answer (score 1):

You may recognize that in your example sentence, "my decision" is the *direct object* and "to you" is the prepositional phrase that is the indirect object.  [More on direct and indirect objects of English verbs.](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm)

Another example:

> I will give **you** my answer tomorrow.
>   I will give my answer **to you** tomorrow.

Either way, "you" is the indirect object.  When forming the passive it's most common to use the direct object, not the indirect object.

> **My answer** will be given to you tomorrow (by me).

However, it's not unusual to use the indirect object with certain verbs like *give*:

> **You** will be given my answer tomorrow (by me).

Similarly, in your example, either is possible.  The problem is with the verb *conveyed* which sounds very formal.  The image is that the decision will be *physically* transported by a messenger, as with an old-fashioned, formal communication from a high-ranking government official.

There's nothing wrong with this if that is what you want to say.  Be aware, though, that almost any combination of this sentence may sound *condescending*, as if a person with power is sending their decision to a person with lesser power.  Often, the more formal the language, the more condescending the nuance.

Again, nothing wrong if that is your intent -- but if not, then it would be better to rephrase it as a request:

> Is it all right if I let you know in a week?
>
> I can give you my decision in a week, if that's OK?

With requests, you would not use the passive voice.  Also, it's probably better to avoid more formal verbs like *convey* and instead use *send* or *give*.